# Insert multiple lines with for-loop in string created with readlines()

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, readlines

I am trying to insert multiple lines in a string which I have created with readlines() in python. I did many hours of debugging on it but I can't figure out what the problem is.

I have a number i of servers which is defined previously. 'data' is a string which includes my textdocument and I have a function 'get_line' which searches the string for the keyword 'Queue1 Position' and returns the line. In my example the line is 82.

...

```
data = cfg.readlines()
```

...

```
#Queue
i = int(gwi["Server"][0]) #Number of Servers
line_idx=get_line(data,'Queue1 Position')
for x in range(1,i+1):
    if x==1:
        data[line_idx] = ('Queue'+str(x)+' Position { 1.500000  '+str(1.100000-x+1)+'  0.000000  m }\n'+'Queue'+str(x)+
        ' Points { {  1.500  '+str(0.700-x+1)+'  0.000  m  }  {  2.500  '+str(0.700-x+1)+'  0.000  m  } }\n\n')
        print(line_idx) #test
    else:
        line_idx = line_idx + 1
        data[line_idx] = ('Queue'+str(x)+' Position { 1.500000  '+str(1.100000-x+1)+'  0.000000  m }\n'+'Queue'+str(x)+
            ' Points { {  1.500  '+str(0.700-x+1)+'  0.000  m  }  {  2.500  '+str(0.700-x+1)+'  0.000  m  } }\n\n')
        print(line_idx) #test
```

[My Document which I edit looks like that at the beginning.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuV0a.jpg)

[When I run my code the cfg- file looks like that. 'Server1 NextComponent { EntitySink1 }' is cut.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3cfp.jpg)

[But when I run my code the result should be like that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F59t.jpg)

Is it even possible to solve this problem with a for loop? Maybe there is another solution.

Comment: Images of text should be avoided as they aren't accessible, nor are they searchable. Instead [edit] the question and paste the text in and format it as code by using the button in the editor, or by indenting it by four spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem on my own.

```
#Queue
i = int(gwi["Server"][0]) #Number of Servers
line_idx=get_line(data,'Queue1 Position')
del data[line_idx+1]
queue_text = ""
for x in range(1,i+1):
    if x<i:
        queue_text = queue_text+('Queue'+str(x)+' Position { 1.500000  '+str(1.100000-x+1)+'  0.000000  m }\n'+'Queue'+str(x)+
        ' Points { {  1.500  '+str(0.700-x+1)+'  0.000  m  }  {  2.500  '+str(0.700-x+1)+'  0.000  m  } }\n\n')
    else:
        queue_text = queue_text+('Queue'+str(x)+' Position { 1.500000  '+str(1.100000-x+1)+'  0.000000  m }\n'+'Queue'+str(x)+
        ' Points { {  1.500  '+str(0.700-x+1)+'  0.000  m  }  {  2.500  '+str(0.700-x+1)+'  0.000  m  } }\n')
data[line_idx] = queue_text
```